# Find center of each square inside perspective square (2D)

Tags: 2d, perspective, centroid

I'm having problems with math while trying to find centroids of each square inside one bigger square/plane.

Simply, I have one plane with same width and height, which contains 11*11 equaly sized smaller squares (see picture below) - in short, grid.
Then having any perspective of that plane defined by 4 points in 2D space (green or orange dots on the picture):

```
Point topLeft;
Point topRight;
Point bottomLeft;
Point bottomRight;
```

[image]

How do I calculate center of any given square (blue dot) of the plane with the perspective defined by those 4 2D points?

```
Point getSquareCenter(Point topLeft, Point topRight, Point bottomLeft, Point bottomRight, int i, int j);
```

Where i, j represents index of 11*11 "matrix of squares". Blue dot is center that supposed to be returned with i = 8 and j = 8.

The only thing I was able to calculate was center of the square in the middle, which is basically center of the whole plane:

```
int cX = (topLeft.x + topRight.x + bottomLeft.x + bottomRight.x)/4;
int cY = (topLeft.y + topRight.y + bottomLeft.y + bottomRight.y)/4;
```

But I'm having trouble finding centers of other squares because of non-linear perspective.

I would be very grateful for any help.

Alternatively, if there would be a way to calculate the 4 points of given "smaller" square (by i and j)  that would be perfect as the center can be computed from them.

Answer (score 0):

you have to find the center between the top left and the top right then find the center between the bottom left and the bottom right the draw a line and the intersection point is the center of the square here is a image for dimestration [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6svt.png)
there is a typo in the image it is get the center between 'b' and 'd'

Comment: Thanks for the response. But that would find center of the whole plane not center of the given little square (blue dot). I think there is required something like linear interpolation based on index between given points.

Comment: i thought that you wanted to know the center of the whole square i do not know how to find the center of the little squares but i hope you find it and good luck